# How do you explain 'co-integration' to determine spurious regression to a fairly new time series student?

Tags: time-series, correlation, self-study

I would appreciate it if someone could explain the concept of spurious regression intuitively / without it being too technical.

So far the student understands that spurious regression is basically when two processes have no relation with each other, but would still conclude that there is one using statistical significance.

Comment: @gung thanks for the edit, i have realized how bad my initial wording was, lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Clive Granger's Nobel Prize Lecture](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/economics/laureates/2003/granger-lecture.html) contains an excellent explanation and it's not very technical either (no equations). It's one of the best lecture's I've ever watched. Notice how Clive does not even need to use lecture slides! A lesson in teaching time-series and in teaching in general. Perhaps an idea would be to suggest that they watch this lecture.

Comment: thank you graeme, this video is just what i needed.

random fact: i study in the same university that clive granger did, just figured this out after i watched the video, lol

Comment: I think the pearls and magnets example that Clive gives in his lecture is a very good one. Glad you think it's useful.

Comment: By the way, another classic is Michael P. Murray's paper ["A Drunk And Her Dog: An Illustration of Cointegration and Error Correction"](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Courses/434/434Context/Co-integration/Murray93DrunkAndDog.pdf) - both humorous and introductory!

Comment: nice, i just finished reading the drunk and dog paper as i saw your comment. its got a nice example and its a well written introduction to get me started. thank you for all these references! im just an undergraduate but i feel like im well on my way to a phd in statistics. lol

Answer (score 2):

People usually find this a convincing counterexample:

[image]

Source: [Johnson (2008)](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ci700332k)

Comment: dimitriy, thank you for this, i am going to use this cheeky example in my answer for next weeks time series exam.

Comment: To quote xkcd 552, "Correlation doesn't imply causation, but it does waggle its eyebrows suggestively and gesture furtively while mouthing 'look over there'."

Comment: okay, now you have made me want to use  xkcd552's quote in my essay, i hope my professor appreciates it.